# Can we delete or limit item revisions?

Tags: podio

Can we somehow (through the API maybe) delete an item revisions? We really don't need more than 10 revisions per item.

It would avoid getting this irreversible error:

`[13-Sep-2018 14:00:13 America/Montreal] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "This item has exceeded the maximum number of revisions."
Request URL: http://api.podio.com/item/499294283`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of revisions per Podio item is limited to 5000, and currently, there is no way of removing the old revisions yet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wish it would rotate once you reach 5000 instead of crashing, it's kind of a beginner mistake and doesn't make the API look good.

Comment: That was done intentionally :) To catch infinity loops and mistakes like that.